# How to restrict users to see certain data filter in PowerBI?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I am creating a PowerBI report with all data coming from a SQL Server. My global audience are from different area names (US, Western Europe, China...). I also included an Area Filter in the report.

However, what is the best way to restrict user's view based on their area? For example, viewer from US can only see US sales/revenue but cannot see China sales/revenue?

So far, I created different versions of the report (already filtered for Area Name) and give access to each different group of users. But is there any other way to have just one report but give user access to their only area?

But is there any other way to have just one report but give user access to their only area?

Comment: This Question looks like it has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997300/filter-power-bi-report-based-on-current-user?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use Power BI's [Row-level security (RLS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) and then use [USERNAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/username-function-dax) to filter the data based on the current user. For more detailed explanation, see [Using Username() in DAX with Row-Level Security](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-username-in-dax-with-row-level-security/).